# Is there a more efficient way to paste Google sheet rows into Excel columns?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

What I mean is turn this:

[image: row]

into this:

[image: column].

Rows are in a Google sheet and I need Excel columns. 
What I do is paste the row into Excel as it is, then cut it, and paste again, this time transposed.
Is there a smarter way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

You could create another sheet in google sheets and use the transpose function to turn the rows into columns to make them easier to paste into Excel.

If you had data that looked like this in sheets
1
2
3
4
5

You can create another sheet and use =TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:A5). I'm not sure if that helps, but it takes out a step.

Answer (score 0):

With google sheet you can publish them to web.

Personally what i would do is publish your google sheet to web so it now has an address. Then in your excel document i would get data - from other sources - from web. In here put your google sheet address you just created. This will then directly drag that google sheet into your document.

This cuts out a stage. Can i ask what is the need for the data to be transposed in the other document?

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste Transpose.

Try the following keyboard shortcut:

```
Ctrl + Alt + V
E
Enter
```

or if you're on a Mac

```
Ctrl + Command + V
Command + E
Enter
```

Comment: That was my initial idea. Doesn't work. It opens this window https://i.imgur.com/ZCnXZNt.png